# what `foo=bar programname` means

Tags: linux, syntax, macos

While developing a React app, I needed to use some environment variables.
The way to do it is by using this syntax:

```
REACT_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE=abcdef npm start
```

[see reference](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#linux-macos-bash)

My first question is: How does that work? I don't know this linux thing, what's happening behind the scenes?

My second question is: How to I make more scalable? say I have file that looks like that

```
MY_VAR_1=123
MY_VAR_2=23332
MY_VAR_3=3232
```

How do I inject it to the npm process? I tried

```
cat .env | npm start
```

But it doesn't work

I guess after I understand the linux syntax I get be in a better position to use a file instead of inline data.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the first question- it’s just setting an environment variable for the program.
You could achieve the same by first exporting the variable.
Regarding the second question- you have to source (either use the keyword ‘source’ or a dot) the file for it to affect the current session.

easiest might be to add ‘export’ before each line in the file, then

```
. file
program
```